# What does “too anxious to find another instance” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the sentence “he was too anxious to find another instance” mean？ How can I say it another way?

> His famous account serves some a warning to all those who speculate in stocks, real estate, or commodities.... But did he exaggerate? Was this really an example of the       irrationality of crowds? Or **was he too anxious to find another instance of what he called “the great and awful book of human folly”?**

In his book he explained human folly with several examples. In the questioned sentence, I’m not sure if “another instance” means an other different example or “his famous account” itself.

Comment: I think still more context is needed. Yes, "instance" means "an example [or occurrence] of." *What* might be such an instance? Unclear from the quoted amount. Btw, it seems this passage is about investing. Be aware that "account" can mean not only "bank account" but also "story." Again, context is needed, but I suspect that the "story" meaning is more likely.

Comment: A source would be helpful.